# How to use dates in NetSuite ODBC query?

Tags: odbc, netsuite

I'm trying to use a date in an ODBC Query.

This works:

```
select * from accountingPeriod where startdate > sysdate;
```

But these do not:

```
select * from accountingPeriod where startdate > TO_DATE('2019-04-01');
select * from accountingPeriod where startdate > CAST('2021-04-01' as timestamp);
```

Result is then: `SQL Error [400] [S1000]: [NetSuite][SuiteAnalytics Connect JDBC Driver][OpenAccess SDK SQL Engine]Failed to retrieve data. Error ticket# l3ml5hfvaurtwlp4g2ko[400]` or
`[NetSuite][SuiteAnalytics Connect JDBC Driver][OpenAccess SDK SQL Engine]Failed to retrieve data. Error ticket# l3mkzq0bu7tphux0lpkz[400]`

Help appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This did the trick:

```
select * 
  from accountingPeriod 
 where startdate > TO_DATE('2019-04-01','YYYY-MM-DD');
```